# node.js process out of memory error

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, node.js

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation Failed - process out of memory`

I'm seeing this error and not quite sure where it's coming from. The project I'm working on has this basic workflow:

1. Receive XML post from another source
2. Parse the XML using [xml2js](https://github.com/maqr/node-xml2js/)
3. Extract the required information from the newly created JSON object and create a new object.
4. Send that object to connected clients (using socket.io)

Node Modules in use are:

- xml2js
- socket.io
- choreographer
- [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

When I receive an XML packet the first thing I do is write it to a log.txt file in the event that something needs to be reviewed later. I first `fs.readFile` to get the current contents, then write the new contents + the old. The log.txt file was probably around 2400KB around last crash, but upon restarting the server it's working fine again so I don't believe this to be the issue.

I don't see a packet in the log right before the crash happened, so I'm not sure what's causing the crash... No new clients connected, no messages were being sent... nothing was being parsed.

### Edit

Seeing as node is running constantly should I be using `delete <object>` after every object I'm using serves its purpose, such as `var now = new Date()` which I use to compare to things that happen in the past. Or, result object from step 3 after I've passed it to the callback?

### Edit 2

I am keeping a master object in the event that a new client connects, they need to see past messages, objects are deleted though, they don't stay for the life of the server, just until their completed on client side. Currently, I'm doing something like this

```
function parsingFunction(callback) {
    //Construct Object
    callback(theConstructedObject);
}

parsingFunction(function (data) {
   masterObject[someIdentifier] = data;
});
```

### Edit 3

As another step for troubleshooting I dumped the `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` right before the parser starts at the `parser.on('end', function() {..});` and parsed several xml packets. The highest heap used was around 10-12 MB throughout the test, although during normal conditions the program rests at about 4-5 MB. I don't think this is particularly a deal breaker, but may help in finding the issue.

Comment: `new Date()` will certainly not be the issue here, long living object are going to be the problem. I suspect the XML parser to leak here, what's the memory usage of the process? Also, using `gdb` could help to find out whether Node.js or V8 itself is crashing here. Without knowing the code or the XML you're parsing it's hard to give any further advise. You should try to limit the scope of the problem e.g. leave out the sending over Socket.IO, the logging etc. You could also pay a visit to our chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/338/node-js

Comment: Currently I'm dumping the current memory usage every minute, no events should have fired before the last dump and the crash from what the console looks like, but it was RSS: 152829952, vsize 24207360, heapTotal: 5822464, heapUsed: 4961744

Comment: Have you tried `gdb` yet? Without the code there's nothing I can do for you :/

Comment: What platform are you running this on? I've had problems in the past (and continue to have them) with Cygwin

Comment: i had this problem once when i called a func from within a loop. It was supposed to break out but didn't, so it leaked from there. I'd recommend console.logging at start of funcs to see what is being triggered more than it ought to

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are accidentally closing on objects recursively. A crazy example:

```
function f() {
  var shouldBeDeleted = function(x) { return x }

  return function g() { return shouldBeDeleted(shouldBeDeleted) }
}
```

To find what is happening fire up node-inspector and set a break point just before the suspected out of memory error. Then click on "Closure" (below Scope Variables near the right border). Perhaps if you click around something will click and you realize what happens.