# Node JS create large no of CSV files without Out of Memory error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a no of CSV files in Node Js (using fast-csv) but even after using --max-old-space-size=2000000 , I am getting  FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed  as there are large no of size (say 3000 each of size 1.5mb).

Node js is creating each file sequentially as per logic but why size is zero at time of creation and memory is allocated after all files gets generated

Any possible way to individually create files and allocate memory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably show how you're creating those files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually CSV creation is not that hard to do it yourself. When it comes to creating large CSV files, it's best to write line per line to a file instead of first creating everything in memory.

This is my code to create a (large) CSV file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const separator = ',';

var data = [
    {name: 'Sam'  , age: 33.5, place: 'some place, with a separator in'},
    {name: 'Sofie', age: 31  , place: 'some place with "double quotes" in'},
    {name: 'Nic'  , age: 1   , place: 'some place with\na newline in'}
];

// construct csv output stream:
const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, '/test.csv');
const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath, { encoding: 'utf8' });

// add separator indication (So Excel knows what the CSV separator is):
output.write(`sep=${separator}\n`);

// if no data, end creation of file:
if(data.length == 0) {
    output.end(() => {
        console.log('done');
    });
    return;
}

// get headers from first entry:
var headers = Object.keys(data[0]);

// write headers to file:
output.write(`${constructCsvLine(headers)}\n`);

// write the rest of the data:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var entry = data[i];

    var line = [];

    // only get fields that we have in our headers:
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        var key = headers[j];

        var field = entry[key];
        if(field === undefined) field = '';

        line.push(field);
    }

    output.write(`${constructCsvLine(line)}\n`);
}

output.end(() => {
    console.log('done');
});



function constructCsvLine(fields) {
    var encodedFields = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var field = '' + fields[i];

        if(field.includes('"')) field = `"${field.replace(/\"/g, '""')}"`; // replace single quotes with double quotes and enclose in quotes
        if(field.includes(separator)) field = `"${field}"`; // enclose in quotes when separator occurs in field
        if(field.includes("\n")) field = `"${field}"`; // enclose in quotes when newline occrus in field
        field = field.replace(/\n/g, "\r"); // seems to be parsed correctly as newline by Excel

        encodedFields.push(field);
    }
    return encodedFields.join(separator);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase your memory Limit:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 fileName.js
```

Or alternatively use a database like Mongodb.

Comment: I cannot increase size since RAM is 3GB only
Isn't any way memory is allocated to each file as it is created ?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287494/node-js-process-out-of-memory-error